# Enabling infrastructure publishing service SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013

I am having problems trying to enable infrastructure publishing service in SharePoint 2013. On the top level site i have gone to Site Collection Administration and started the service but then when i go to Manage Site Features and try to activate the service it says that i need to activate it via Site Collection Administration and when i go back to there it says it is activated and running.

This service is running fine on another site collection with no issues.

Update: I have created another web application and have enabled the service fine, i still cannot run it on my original web application however.